page not showing after using navigation in react native
im learning react native and i started a simple project but for a reason when i addthe navigation so when i click on log in it take me to the home page its not showing me the login page to start withenter image description hereenter image description hereenter image description here
i tried some import clear the cach but it didnt work

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => loginUse()}>


thank you but still showing nothing

maybe because you have a container with a white background color. and the text on the home screen is also basically white. try to add a colour black to your home screen text.

Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.
